# Restriction on elements depending on attributes in XSD 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define the following situation in my XSD Schema. This is an example of my XML:

```
<initialization>

  <stat name="SelfActualization" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>
  <stat name="Social" range="" init="" tickValue="" colorR="" colorG="" colorB=""/>

  <staticAction name="Study" >
    <SelfActualization reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
    <Social reqPoints="0" gainedPoints="0" />
  </staticAction>

</initialization>
```

I can define as many "stat" elements as I want (in this case only 2) and I already managed to obtain this behavior. What I don't know how to do is: in any of my "StaticActions" I need that all the "stats" previously defined above are  named again (as elements), and in the same order they have been defined at the beginning.
As we can see in the example indeed both "SelfActualization" and "Social" are there and in the right order. If another "stat" not defined before, or if one of the "stats" defined is missing, or if the order is wrong, the XML has to be refused. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, then on the declaration of the initialization element, add the assertion

```
<xs:assert test="every $sa in staticAction 
                 satisfies deep-equal(stat/@name,
                              $sa/child::*/local-name())"/>
```

Comment: Masterfully wielded, the expressive power of XPath 2.0 is delightful.

Comment: Thank you very much, but may I ask you as well how to define the "Static Action" element since it is supposed to contain those elements (the "Stats") whose names are dynamically dependent on the XML and not static ?

Comment: You could define it as xs:anyType, and rely entirely on assertions to constrain the content.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am still trying to figure out how can I do that with assertions. I opened another question for this topic but I have been told that it is not easy because I need to specify many points. May you please edit your answer and show me how to define my elements with xs:anyType and the corresponding attributes with assertions like you suggested? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Isn't the above assertion enough? Define StaticAction as xs:anyType, with the above assertion.